# What is wrong with the "while" condition here?

Tags: python, while-loop

What is wrong with the while condition here

```
while (a = input(">").lower()) != "quit":
    if a == "start":
        print("Car started...Ready to go")
    elif a == "stop":
        print("Car stopped")
```

Comment: Why do you think that there is something wrong with the "while" condition?

Comment: `a := ` is probably what you want there

Comment: @rdas interesting to learn about this new feature, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot assign a value this way in python. If you are using python 3.8 or higher, you can use the so-called [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) like so:

```
while (a := input(">").lower()) != "quit":
    if a == "start":
        print("Car started...Ready to go")
    elif a == "stop":
        print("Car stopped")
```

Otherwise you will need to do something like this:

```
a = input(">").lower()
while a != "quit":
    if a == "start":
        print("Car started...Ready to go")
    elif a == "stop":
        print("Car stopped")
    a = input(">").lower()
```